# (Delphi) Change Socket client name when sending a message

Tags: sockets, delphi, serversocket, delphi-10.1-berlin

For some reason if I send a msg through the client I made it automatically ads the username "license.embarcadero.com:" to it so if I send a msg from the client to the server it comes out as "license.embarcadero.com: (msg)"

How can I change license.embarcadero.com: to what ever I want.
If it helps i'm using berlin update 2

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the client source: (I use the stylemanager for the ui)

```
unit uClient;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  System.Win.ScktComp;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    pnl1: TPanel;
    grp1: TGroupBox;
    grp2: TGroupBox;
    mmochat: TMemo;
    edtchat: TEdit;
    btnsend: TButton;
    lbl1: TLabel;
    edtip: TEdit;
    lbl2: TLabel;
    edtport: TEdit;
    btnconnect: TButton;
    lblstatus: TLabel;
    clntsckt1: TClientSocket;
    procedure btnconnectClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure clntsckt1Connect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
    procedure clntsckt1Read(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
    procedure clntsckt1Disconnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
    procedure btnsendClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btnsendClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  clntsckt1.Socket.SendText(edtchat.Text);
  mmochat.Lines.Add('Me: ' + edtchat.Text);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnconnectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  edtip.Enabled := False;
  edtport.Enabled := False;
  btnconnect.Enabled := False;

  clntsckt1.Host := edtip.Text;
  clntsckt1.Port := StrToInt(edtport.Text);
  clntsckt1.Active := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.clntsckt1Connect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  mmochat.Clear;
end;

procedure TForm1.clntsckt1Disconnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  lblstatus.Caption := 'Disconnected...';
end;

procedure TForm1.clntsckt1Read(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  mmochat.Lines.Add(clntsckt1.Socket.ReceiveText);
end;

end.
```

Here is the server source: (I use the stylemanager for the ui)

```
unit uServer;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  System.Win.ScktComp, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    pnl1: TPanel;
    grp1: TGroupBox;
    mmochat: TMemo;
    grp2: TGroupBox;
    lbl1: TLabel;
    edtport: TEdit;
    lbl2: TLabel;
    lbl3: TLabel;
    edtstatus: TEdit;
    btnlisten: TButton;
    srvrsckt1: TServerSocket;
    btnstop: TButton;
    lst1: TListBox;
    edtchat: TEdit;
    btnsend: TButton;
    procedure btnlistenClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure srvrsckt1ClientConnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
    procedure btnstopClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnsendClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure srvrsckt1ClientRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btnsendClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  srvrsckt1.Socket.Connections[0].SendText('server: ' + edtchat.Text);
  mmochat.Lines.Add('server: ' + edtchat.Text);
  edtchat.Clear;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnlistenClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  port : Integer;
begin
  btnlisten.Enabled := False;
  btnstop.Enabled := True;
  edtport.Enabled := False;

  port := StrToInt(edtport.Text);
  srvrsckt1.Port := port;
  srvrsckt1.Active := True;
  edtstatus.Text := 'Listening...';
end;

procedure TForm1.btnstopClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  btnlisten.Enabled := True;
  btnstop.Enabled := False;
  edtport.Enabled := True;

  srvrsckt1.Active := False;
  edtstatus.Text := 'Stopped Listening...';
end;

procedure TForm1.srvrsckt1ClientConnect(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  lst1.Items.Add(Socket.RemoteHost + '  ' + Socket.RemoteAddress);
end;

procedure TForm1.srvrsckt1ClientRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  mmochat.Lines.Add(Socket.RemoteHost + ': ' + Socket.ReceiveText);
end;

end.
```

Comment: there is no way anyone can answer this. We can't see your code, or know anything about how your client and server communicate, or how your UIs work, or what you changed to break them.

Comment: I updated it. thx for the info

Comment: Which IP address do you get for license.embarcadero.com?

Comment: Don't know, but my guess would be that you have a network license for Delphi, and are using the same port as the license server. Try a different port number

Comment: @Dsm a different port number will not change the computer name (DNS entry)

Comment: Thanks for all your help. It seems that if I have the client and server on the same pc it does that. Is there a way that i can change the name instead of it using the computer name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the screenshot the "Connected Users" window in the right lower corner shows

```
license.embarcadero.com 127.0.0.1
```

So I assume your [hosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) file contains an entry like

```
127.0.0.1 license.embarcadero.com
```

The socket server performs a reverse DNS lookup for the IP address of the incoming connection and displays the associated name, which is license.embarcadero.com

So this is a problem only for localhost connections. Clients on a different computer will not show up with the same server name.

Comment: Thanks for that. Is it possible to change the name? Because currently it uses the computer name

Comment: @Newb101 you are currently displaying the peer's `RemoteHost`, which is the hostname that the peer's IP address resolves to. If you want to display something else, then just do so. There is nothing stopping you from using anything else other than the `RemoteHost`. For instance, have each client send a username immediately after connecting, store that in the `TCustomWinSocket.Data` property, and display that on each message received.